# QMdiArea: First tab works fine, second tab's content is way too small

Tags: qt, tabs, qt5, qlayout, qmdiarea

*Situation*: As the central widget of my application I have a *QMdiArea* in tabbed mode (wrapped in a custom class that inherited from *QMdiArea*). When I now add the first *QMdiSubWindow* via `addSubWindow()` everything is still fine, meaning the window and its contents are maximized to take up all the space of the *QMdiArea*. However, as soon as I add a second sub window, the following problem arises:

*Problem*: The content of the second window is not displayed, but instead the content from the first continues to (despite the fact that the second tab visually has the focus), but is reduced in size. It only takes up a few pixels. But if I now switch back to the first sub window/tab (either by clicking into the size-reduced widget which then automatically goes back to max size or by selecting the first tab header) and then selecting the 2nd again, all is fine = the widget/editor of the 2nd tab is now displayed and is maximized.

But only until I close the second tab, in which case the content from the first is displayed (as expected), but again only in the small size!

*Screenshot:*
[image: Screenshot outlining the issue]

Another related test case: 1st tab is created and is displayed full size as expected. If I now simply resize the overall *QMainWindow*, suddenly a faint border appears around the widget in my tab. So it appears to be in a mixed state between maximized and normal mode with borders. Does that create any new leads?

*Screenshot:*

[image: Screenshot outlining the related issue]

I am so far not using any explicitly defined layouts, but given that the first tab works fine and after manual back-and-forth switching all others as well, I assume that it should work without.

Do I need to set explicit layout objects? Why does it work for the first tab, but not the second?

Some code as a base: This is the logic executed in my custom *QMdiArea* class that takes care of adding the new children:

```cpp
// Note: pEditor inherits from / is a QMdiSubWindow itself

if(!pEditor->isInitialized())
{
    pEditor->initialize();
    pEditor->setWidget(pEditor->getEditorWidget()); 
    pEditor->setInitialized(true);
}

pEditor->beforeDisplay();

addSubWindow(pEditor);
pEditor->showMaximized();

// HACK START
pExisting = subWindowList().at(0);
if(pExisting)
    setActiveSubWindow(pExisting);
// HACK END
```

***Update:*** Added the hack [proposed by N1ghtLight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999587/qmdiarea-first-tab-works-fine-second-tabs-content-is-way-too-small?noredirect=1#comment40803299_25999587). Marked as such in the coding.

***Update 2:*** Edited / correct problem description + new test-case with screenshot.

Comment: Have your tried to call void QMdiArea::setActiveSubWindow(QMdiSubWindow * window) for your just created new pEditor instance of the QMdiSubWindow?. For example, call it after addSubWindow(pEditor). Also I'm wondering if the call of showMaximized is needed at all.

Comment: @N1ghtLight: That doesn't change anything. The new tab is already active (see my newly added screenshot). Regarding `showMaximized()`: If I omit that, the widget inside the sub window would not be displayed at all, since it never get set to *visible*.

Comment: for now, the ugly workaround really can be the calling of setActiveSubWindow twice - for some available sub mdi and then for the newly created sub. This should emulate the situation when you click on first and then return to second. Also I have a feeling that previous time when I used mdi (3 years ago) I have the same issue and just stopped on such ugly workaround :)

Comment: @N1ghtLight That indeed works. Thank you for the tip! I am however hoping that we are able to find a "proper" solution. But feel free to add your idea as an answer. It might get the bounty if nothing better pops up.

Comment: here it's link to my test project with mdi sub windows creation ... https://mega.co.nz/#!n1MQRDaQ!Ca-d-gSPnPfhsL9tmrjvdSrrD_0lzdIf26bbUY-AraY ... unfortunately, it works fine for me ... this makes me think that it's something wrong with sizing of mdiSubWindow content in your project

Comment: @N1ghtLight Update: Thank you for the example. Works for me as well and for three days I have now been trying to duplicate that in my application (even using your TextEditWidget for testing). Without success so far. But I realized something regarding which editor widget is too small: it is the original/first and the second one isn't visible at all! See update in my original post.

Comment: have your tried to hide() the QMdiArea instance before your add new sub window, and after all adding work is done call show() on MDIArea? I saw somewhere adding of new sub windows is done in this way. If this will fix it, then the problem in redrawing/resizing of layouts.

Comment: Doesn't fix it, makes it worse instead: Even the first widget is not maximized anymore (well it has the max. size but displayed as a regular window with border) and there never is a second widget for the second tab created or at least it never gets visible even after going back to the 1st and then back to the 2nd.

Comment: well, if you can share the project with me, I will able to take a look

Comment: @N1ghtLight I will look into stripping down my application into a minimal example project showcasing the issue and then share it (if I shouldn't find the issue myself during the reduction process). That will however most likely take a day or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of comparing the example project from *N1ightLight* to my own implementation, I finally came across the central differences. There were in fact two issues at play:

1. For some reason I had the following line in the creation of my MDI sub windows, which apparently screwed up the size handling. Getting rid of this line removed any need for the previously proposed hack. Combined with the layouting proposed by N1ghtLight, all size changes are now handled gracefully.

   ```
   setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized); // do not use that state!
   ```
2. The second part regarding the tab closing (closing one tab did not bring up the next tab in the expected manner and size), is actually explained in the Qt documentation:

   > When you create your own subwindow, you must set the Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose widget attribute if you want the window to be deleted when closed in the MDI area. If not, the window will be hidden and the MDI area will not activate the next subwindow.

   Since I was creating my own sub windows I had to set that flag, but I never did because I wanted to prevent Qt from automatically deleting my content widget as well. My solution now is that I set the flag, but whenever a MDI child is about to be closed, I remove the link to the widget, so Qt cannot delete it.

   ```
   void CustomMDIWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* pEvent)
   {
       setWidget(0);
       pEvent->accept();
   }
   ```

I will mark my own answer as the correct one, but will award the bounty to *N1ightLight* since his support eventually led to me finding the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly workaround really can be the calling of `setActiveSubWindow()` twice: First for some available sub window and then for the newly created one. This should emulate the situation when you click on the first tab and then return to the second one.

Comment: As explained in my now edited/corrected problem description, this solves only the tab creation stage. When I close an existing tab, I ran into the same/similar issue. Given that at this point there is only one tab remaining, there is no second tab to temporarily switch to via `setActiveSubWindow()`.